# Proving a subring of $\Bbb Z[\zeta_{11}]$ is PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Check if $\Bbb Z[\zeta_{11}+\zeta_{11}^{-1}]$ is PID where $\zeta_{11}$ is primitive $11$-th root of unity.

I don't know how to proceed? Are there any techniques in algebraic number theory to tackle this kind of problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Finding the class numbers of real-cyclotomic fields is hard work. Proving that the class number is $1$ involves proving that every unit is a cyclotomic unit.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Proving $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1}]$ has class number $1$ for $p\leq 11$ is trivial, some educated guessing can handle the case $p\leq 19$. But *ad hoc* method goes not much beyond that.

Comment: @pisco, well, maybe "trivial" is not a useful way to describe proving class number one here... :)   But, yes, "yields to standard methods" and/or "is well-known". :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, the discriminant of $K = \mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{11}+\zeta_{11}^{-1}]$ is $11^4$, so Minkowski's bound is $\leq 4$.

However, both primes $2$ and $3$ are inert in $K$, so there is no ideal of norm $2, 3$ or $4$. Therefore the class group is trivial.

In the same way, one can prove, without any calculation, $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p+\zeta_p^{-1}]$ is a PID when $p=13$; while $p=17,19$ require some computations and clever ideas.

Comment: Thank you! How can we compute $disc\ O := disc(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{11}+\zeta_{11}^{-1}])$? This is an order of $\mathcal O_K=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{11}]$ so we have the relation $disc O=[O_K:O]^2 disc O_K$ so I am confused since here $disco\ O =11^4 < disc \mathcal O_K = -11^9$?

Comment: @PerelMan  $O = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{11}+\zeta_{11}^{-1}]$ is not an order of $\mathcal{O}_K$ because its fractional field is not $K=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{11}]$. There are numerous ways to compute the discriminant, both elementary and advanced. One advanced way is via the different ideal, the ramification index of $p$ in $O$ is $(p-1)/2$, the ramification is tame, so different ideal is $\mathfrak{P}^{(p-1)/2-1}$, its norm is the discriminant, namely $p^{(p-3)/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is equivalent to show that the class number (= the order of the ideal class group) of the field $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{11}+\zeta_{11}^{-1})$ is $1$. More generally, denote $K_m=\mathbf Q(\zeta_m), K_m^+$ = the maximal totally real subfield of $K_m$, $h_m$ and $h_m^+$ their respective class numbers. It is a classical result that $h_m^+$ divides $h_m$; write $h_m=h_m^+ h_m^-$. The "minus" class number $h_m^-$ may be considered as known, thanks to an analytical formula giving it in terms of Bernoulli numbers (see e.g. Washington, "Introduction to cyclotomic fields", thm. $4.17$). The "plus" class number $h_m^+$ is much more difficult to compute. Around $1975$, using deep results of Odlyzko on lower bounds of discriminants of number fields, Masley was able to determine *all* the $K_m$ with $m\neq 2$ mod $4$ for which $h_m=1$. A complete (finite) list is given in *op. cit.*, thm. $11.1$. In particular, for an odd prime $p$, it appears in that list that $h_p =1$ for all $p\neq 23,29,31,37$. "Horrendeous" *ad hoc* calculations show e.g. that $h_{23}^+=1$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/90005/300700 and
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2024190/300700, but the problem of the determination of all $p$ for which $h_p^+=1$ remains unsolved in general. To have an idea of the computational difficulties, see e.g. R. Schoof's paper "Class Numbers of Real Cyclotomic Fields of Prime Conductor" (2002), in which the author stresses that " the class numbers $h_p^+$
are notoriously hard to compute. Indeed, the number $h_p^+$ is not known for a
single prime p ≥ 71."